# Is it a good idea to index datetime field in mysql?

Tags: mysql, indexing

I am working on designing a large database. In my application I will have many rows for example I currently have one table with 4 million records. Most of my queries use datetime clause to select data. Is it a good idea to index datetime fields in mysql database?

```
Select field1, field2,.....,field15
from table where field 20 between now() and now + 30 days
```

I am trying to keep my database working good and queries being run smoothly

More, what idea do you think I should have to create a high efficiency database?

Comment: What's `field 20`?

Comment: `BETWEEN` is "inclusive".  That is it includes the midnight or day at the end of the range.  (In the case of `NOW()`, then one extra second is included.)

Answer (score 216, accepted):

MySQL recommends using indexes for a variety of reasons including elimination of rows between conditions: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html

This makes your datetime column an excellent candidate for an index if you are going to be using it in conditions frequently in queries.  If your only condition is `BETWEEN NOW() AND DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)` and you have no other index in the condition, MySQL <strike>will</strike> *may* have to do a *full table scan* on <strike>every query</strike> *some queries*.  I'm not sure how many rows are generated in 30 days, but as long as it's less than about 1/3 (some say 20%) of the total rows it will be more efficient to use an index on the column.

Your question about creating an efficient database is very broad.  I'd say to just make sure that it's normalized and all appropriate columns are indexed (i.e. ones used in joins and where clauses).

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. That really help. I am sure I will have more filters to it. I just want to make sure indexing datetime field is a good idea or not as we may have duplicate date time. but you answer explained it :)  Thank you

Comment: +1 for 'ones used in joins and where clauses'. A great rule of thumb for an indexing strategy. Obvious now I think about it, but hadn't occurred to me before

Comment: But if you query the data with date *range*, such as data range from "2017-01-01 11:20" to "2018-01-03 12:12", it doesn't make `SELECT` query faster even though I indexed `date time` column... index make query fast when I use `equal` operation.. Am i right?

Comment: How about if querying datetime fields with time functions like DAY(datetime) or HOUR(datetime). Will the index help or hinder in this case?

Comment: hi @Explosion Pills, if I only need to query the table base on year and month, will I get a better performance if I created a new column with only year and month then index it, instead of create an index of the datetime column directly? Such as that I create a column whose value is like 201801.

Comment: "If..., will have to do a full table scan on every query" -- WHAT???  In fact, you contradict that in the next sentence.  I modified the sentence.

Comment: @user3595632 - That is a year's range -- probably such a large fraction that it would be faster to eschew the INDEX and simply do a table scan.

Comment: @cronoklee - NO.  Functions make the condition not [_sargable_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable) .

Comment: @WoodsChen - The range works just fine, though a little messy.  I like to say `WHERE col >= '2023-02-25' AND col < '2023-02-25' + INTERVAL 7 DAY` so I won't have to worry about date arithmetic and leap years.

Answer (score 25):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4594229/mysql-integer-vs-datetime-index) author performed tests showed that integer unix timestamp is better than DateTime. Note, he used MySql. But I feel no matter what DB engine you use comparing integers are slightly faster than comparing dates so int index is better than DateTime index. Take T1 - time of comparing 2 dates, T2 - time of comparing 2 integers. Search on indexed field takes approximately O(log(rows)) time because index based on some balanced tree - it may be different for different DB engines but anyway Log(rows) is common estimation. (if you not use bitmask or r-tree based index). So difference is (T2-T1)*Log(rows) - may play role if you perform your query oftenly.

Comment: Thank you. I was thinking about that as an option but did not know how to approach it. I believe you are absolutely right integers are always faster.

Comment: Better? I doubt a unix timestamp is better for _all_ cases. Yes, storing an integer is generally faster than storing a string, but what about all the [DateTime functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html) MySQL exposes? Implementing them yourself would either have a negative effect on performance or functionality.

Comment: I work with a legacy web application where the developer insisted on using unix timestamps for everything in the database. It was an absolute nightmare to work with dates for years because of this and I have spent a lot of time migrating everything to datetime or timestamp SQL fields wherever I could. I'm sure there are cases where unix timestamps are useful but generally I think you're best avoiding them.

Comment: Yeah, MySQL stores dates using a 5-byte representation (separating year, month, etc.) which is kind of weird.

Comment: The performance differences among `TIMESTAMP`, `DATETIME`, `INT`, and `BIGINT` are not worth worrying about.  On the other hand, beware of DST (daylight saving stupidity) and its extra or repeated hour.

Answer (score 10):

I know this question was asked years ago, but I just found my solution.
I added an index to a datetime column.
I went from 1.6 seconds of calling the last 600 records sorted by datetime, and after adding the index, it came down to 0.0028 seconds. I'd say it's a win.

```
ALTER TABLE `database`.`table` 
ADD INDEX `name_of_index`   (`datetime_field_from_table`);
```