# Large Mysql Table Indeces

Tags: mysql, database, indexing

I am storing in a MySQL database messages crawled from web sources. The Table is very simple  Just an INT id, the JSON message and a date time. I have a primary index on the id and an index on the date time. Now I realized that for some reason the mysql operations are very slow . The database contains more than 200M rows.

Is there a problem with the indexes I am using?

Also I am thinking of partitioning the data per day in order to increase the performance is this correct? Do I have any benefit of using a NoSQL database like CoutchDB since I use only JSON documents?

Also the table is very large (200GB) is there a way to create more compact indexes using compression?

INSERTS:More than 10M per day
SELECTS:Depends on System. Probably Selects using date time. Selects will return around 60M rows .
UPDATES:-
DELETES:-

Comment: you can take a look to 

[http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?24,499167,499167][1]

and

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15425230/is-it-a-good-idea-to-index-datetime-field-in-mysql][2]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15425230/is-it-a-good-idea-to-index-datetime-field-in-mysql
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15425230/is-it-a-good-idea-to-index-datetime-field-in-mysql

Comment: What queries do you run against the data? what is the frequency of create/update/read/delete operations? What database engine is this? How is your DBMS configured? How slow?

Answer (score 3):

maybe its not about this table.
if you want to know witch process makes mysql slow, use following command:

```
show processlist;
```

and look at time column, the greater one makes your mysql slow

Answer (score 0):

You already have 2 viable options :

- partion the table by day (or by nb of rows)
- use a nosql db

But this depends hugely on what you are doing with the json data , if you need to extract only some entries which have in the json some specific attribute then i recommend the nosql otherwise if you only retrieve data based on date or id then use mysql sharding.