# Any advantage in indexing a DATE column?

Tags: mysql, sql

In mysql, is there any benefit to adding an index to a `DATE` column? I will be using the column for comparisons such as:

```
SELECT * FROM birthdays WHERE date > today + 3 days;
```

Would indexing the `date` column improve performance here?

Comment: If there are enough rows, of course, but your query is syntactically wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it will avoid some full scan by eliminating some rows in condition.

Check out this thread, it's well explained :

[Is it a good idea to index datetime field in mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15425230/is-it-a-good-idea-to-index-datetime-field-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can use it to do a range scan in the query you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Index will improve performance.

Without index mysql will have to scan **all** rows.

With index - it will create sorted "array", so it will be able to use binary search to find where `today+3` starts and just scan all **further** rows of this array instead of full scan.