# How to decrease the searching time in MySQL DB when searching for a range of dates?

Tags: mysql, search

I performed a search on MySQL on the following table that has following columns and indexes:

[image: columns]

[image: indexes]

The query was the following, please notice the number of days as 6:

```
SELECT * FROM data WHERE TEMP<"3000" AND TEMP>"2600" AND Date_Time >"2016-05-05 %" and Date_Time <"2016-05-11 %";
```

This query returns the results in `0.59s`

If I change the number of days to more than that like in this query then I will get the result in a lot more time `2.15s`

```
SELECT * FROM data WHERE TEMP<"3000" AND TEMP>"2600" AND Date_Time >"2016-05-04 %" and Date_Time <"2016-05-11 %";
```

How do I fix this issue? I find it absurd that only another day affects the speed that much! I am aiming to search in a wider range of time, so I somewhat need to know the reason behind this.

[image: explain statements]

Comment: Intresting issue. Try to add composite index (TEMP, Date_Time). Any speed changes?

Comment: Consider using the between clause. Here you can see that it indeed improves performance: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15425230/is-it-a-good-idea-to-index-datetime-field-in-mysql

Comment: Can you add explain results for both queries?

Comment: @arhey, I did this `alter table data add index(TEMP,Date_Time)` but no difference in speed

Comment: I will include the explanations in a second.

Comment: Second query does not use index (key column) and scan 267140 rows instead of 41004 if first query. I am guessing you added composite index named TEMP2. Try to add FORCE INDEX (TEMP_2) before where

Comment: Only now I noticed that you have to ranges in condition. So composite index is useless. Try to add  FORCE INDEX (TEMP)

Comment: maybe it has to do with the ordering, ever thought of it like that? try to add order to it maybe make it descending, also use built in date_funcs

Comment: @arhey using `FORCE INDEX(TEMP)` before where actually made it slower :/ `3.02s`

Comment: @Elltz, do you mean order by? Could elaborate on how I should do that?!

Comment: Try to FORCE INDEX(Date_Time)

Comment: Oh, this one is working. Could you explain why it worked and the other didn't worked? Also, why did the slow query of type all instead of range?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fact 1: **MySQL cannot use more than 1 index in your case**
As explained in this blog post https://www.percona.com/blog/2009/09/12/3-ways-mysql-uses-indexes/

> if you have index on (A,B) This index can be used to lookup rows for
>   WHERE clauses like A=5 ; A BETWEEN 5 AND 10 ; A=5 AND B BETWEEN 5 AND
>   10 it however will NOT be able to help lookup rows for B BETWEEN 5 AND
>   10 predicate because it is not index prefix.

So, in your case that you have the columns TEMP and Date_Time and you search by range, the range index will be used for either TEMP or Date_Time and the second part of the query will be executed using where. This is structural limitation of BTREE indexes.

Fact 2: **The index is not covering your query, which means query cannot be executed using only data from the index without reading the row itself**

> A full table scan is performed using reads from the index to look up data rows > in index order. Uses index does not appear in the Extra column.
>   http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain-output.html#jointype_range

So what happens in your first query:
 1. MySQL will lookup for Date_Time in Date_Time index and choose the index_rows that fit '*Date_Time >"2016-05-05 %" and Date_Time <"2016-05-11 %"*'
 2. In the index the TEMP info is not available, so MySQL needs to collect all the index_rows from the data table.
 3. MySQL will evaluate the condition 'TEMP<"3000" AND TEMP>"2600"' on each one of these rows.

What happens in the second query?
MySQL decides not to use any of the available indexes (possible_keys) and performs a full table scan to return the values. This means that each row of the table will be scanned to check if matches the conditions *TEMP<"3000" AND TEMP>"2600" AND Date_Time >"2016-05-04 %" and Date_Time <"2016-05-11 %"*.
This probably happens because there is no value with prefix "2016-05-11" or "2016-05-04".

Comment: Thank you @fathineos. Which part do you mean by my second part of the query? Because I just tried this statement `SELECT * FROM data WHERE  Date_Time >"2016-05-10 %" and Date_Time <"2016-05-16 %";` and I got the result in about `0.79 sec`. When I increased the date by one day to `"Date_Time <"2016-05-17 %"`, the latency then became `2.43 sec` So in this case it is only the Date_Time column that was used, is it still the same situation?!

Comment: Your query performs a search 1) on 'Date_Time' and 2) on 'TEMP'. I see you've created an index for each one of these columns. Though, the problem is that MySQL can use only one of these indexes in your case. This applies on both of your queries. 

So why is the second slower?
The problem is that the second query doesn't use any index at all (Key is NULL in explain output). 

How to overcome this?
You probably need to force MySQL to use the Date_Time index as @arhey mentioned.