# MySQL - need help .One table or multiple tables?

Tags: mysql, sql

I must to make a decision if I split my table in more tables or I keep all in one table. According to my calculation if I will keep all in one table my table will have estimated 300.000 rows per year. Some people say to me to split table for every year. example 2019_table..
Some people say to split table in 4 tables(subcategories). I need an advice how to do it.

This is my current table https://ibb.co/jfZMKQJ

Answer (score 2):

300K records is not really a large amount, and even over a decade, it is only 3 million records, which also is not very large.  Assuming you can tune your database with appropriate indices, I don't see any reason to split into multiple tables.  Even if you did have the need for this, you could try something like partitioning the table first ([see the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/partitioning.html)).

Comment: but if I have 3 million records and that data will be accessed by 2000 users in the same time will be some delay or this depends on the server hardware performance?

Comment: @Florin It may be a problem. It would not be solved by splitting the table.

Answer (score 1):

300K records is not a large amount. Instead of splitting the tables, you better have to put an index on your datetime field assuming it is one of the fields you will use to filter your data.

See this answer for more details: [Is it a good idea to index datetime field in mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15425230/is-it-a-good-idea-to-index-datetime-field-in-mysql)