# Add a stored generated column in a big table

Tags: mysql

I have a datetime column `activities.done_at` in my MySQL DB. As I run many queries on the date part of that column, and for indexing reasons, I'd like a date column `activities.done_on` with  only the date part of `done_at`.

I added a VIRTUAL generated column like below. It works fine, but doesn't help with the performances as the VIRTUAL column cannot be indexed.

```sql
ALTER TABLE activities 
ADD COLUMN done_on date GENERATED ALWAYS AS (cast(`done_at` as date)) VIRTUAL;
```

So I want to add instead a STORED generated column:

```sql
ALTER TABLE activities 
ADD COLUMN done_on date GENERATED ALWAYS AS (cast(`done_at` as date)) STORED;
```

While the first `ADD COLUMN` was very fast, the STORED one is very long and times out. I cannot manage to run it. My table has 45 million rows.

Is there a way to add it anyway?

Comment: Why do you think virtual columns can't be indexed?

Comment: From the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-secondary-indexes.html): Even with additional write costs, secondary indexes on virtual columns may be preferable to generated stored columns, which are materialized in the clustered index, resulting in larger tables that require more disk space and memory.

Comment: If you apply a bit of common sense: adding virtual generated columns only modify table header data as the expression is evaluated when you query it, while stored generated columns require the data to be stored within the table data file. The latter could take a while on a 45mill row table.

Comment: I use MariaDB 10.3 which functions as a replacement of MySQL 5.7 and indeed the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html) says it's ok to add indexes on VIRTUAL generated columns. But there seems to be an issue as an EXPLAIN SELECT on a given date shows 5M rows, while there should be only a few hundred rows at most for that day. I thought it was because of a useless index.

Comment: `CAST()` is a function, thereby making it impossible to use the index (at least for the Virtual case) -- see [_sargable_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable)

Comment: The `VIRTUAL` is simply declarative; the `STORED` must [essentially] rebuild the entire table.

Answer (score 0):

As recently as MariaDB 10.3.26 and 10.5.7, there was a potential crash when using indexed virtual columns.  So, upgrade to at least one of those, then go ahead and use indexing with virtual.

What kind of queries are you doing?

```
WHERE col >= '2023-10-10'
  AND col  < '2023-10-10' + INTERVAL 1 DAY

WHERE col >= '2020-01-01'
  AND col  < '2020-01-01' + INTERVAL 3 YEAR
```

Those are essentially as fast for `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP` as for `DATE`
(And The above syntax works for all datatypes.)

Comment: I use MariaDB 10.3.39 so I should be ok here.

It's indeed those kind of queries, but I don't want to use my DateTime column as it's not indexed. I feel uneasy indexing a DateTime column. As I only care about the date part, I'd rather index that.

Comment: @jibai31 - is the goal to find those activities done during precisely one day?  My first sample WHERE shows how to do that efficiently with an index on a `DATETIME col`.  No need for the hassle with a Generated `DATE` column.  Sure, `WHERE date_col = '2023-10-10'` is nice and simple.  But, if you need to check for a whole week, you are stuck with a "range" query like both of my examples.

Comment: Further...  If you would have `WHERE user_id = 123 AND col ...` then the optimal index is a "composite":  `INDEX(user_id, col)`.  Simple.  Efficient.  Works for `DATE`, `DATETIME`, `TIMESTAMP`, etc.

Comment: I was under the impression that indexes on datetime col were not recommended. It seems I was wrong, I see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15425230/is-it-a-good-idea-to-index-datetime-field-in-mysql) that it should be ok.

Comment: @jibai31 - I bled over lots of that Question and its Answers.  Take another look.